# Why does main() compiled by D have a 32-bit return value on a 64-bit machine?

Tags: assembly, d

Here is a very small source file in D:

```
void main()
{
}
```

and here objdump's disassembly of the .o file:

```
Disassembly of section .text._Dmain:
0000000000000000 <_Dmain>:
void main()
   0:   55                      push   %rbp
   1:   48 8b ec                mov    %rsp,%rbp
   4:   31 c0                   xor    %eax,%eax
{
   6:   5d                      pop    %rbp
   7:   c3                      retq
```

The compiler is DMD64 D Compiler v2.056 running on an x86_64 Linux machine.

What I wonder is why only 32-bit EAX is being cleared rather than the whole 64-bit RAX?  I assume this is a return value, required just as in a C program even if not acknowledged in D source.

Comment: This doesn't look like optimized code. I wouldn't try to reason about unoptimized code because many things in it are completely redundant and avoidable like all the above instructions except `retq`.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
xor    %eax,%eax
```

DOES clear the entire `rax` in x64. Operation on the dword sized registers automatically clear the high dword of the full register.

Comment: No, that is not correct. They are zero-extended. A `mov eax, -1` for example makes `rax` contain `ffffffff`. `mov ecx,0FFFFFFFFh` `mov rax,0FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFh` `mov eax,ecx` does too.